# How to set table with yes no checkbox to mysql using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

please help me with this:
Using Laravel

- Function/Purpose:

Guest (no register/login) - completed <have a login/Register - working>

- Objective:

Survey Form with basic text field: fname, lname, ID Number, mobile and then 3 questions with `yes` and `no` checkbox.

- My challenge:
  I dont know what to place for the 2options survey questions to migrate to DB?

hi Here is my migration create_survey_posts_table.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSurveyPostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('fname');
            $table->string('lname');
            $table->string('id_number');
            $table->string('mobile');
            $table->string('sq-symptoms');
            $table->string('sq-travel');
            $table->string('sq-contact');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('survey_posts');
    }
}
```

what should i use for the `sq-symptoms` as it is a radio button `yes` and `no` options to upload (migrate) to mysql

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your actual question is not easy to understand. Here is a guideline for you on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
<label>Symptoms</label>
       <input type="radio" name="sq-symptoms" value="yes">
      <label for="yes"></label>
</div>

=>if you select radio button your value will be store in database yes and if you not select radio button it is automatic value pass no.

if(isset($request->sq-symptoms)) {
            $post->sq-symptoms= $request->sq-symptoms;
        }else{
            $post->sq-symptoms= 'no';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A radio input with validation maybe?

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Symptoms</legend>
  <label>Yes<input type="radio" name="sq_symptoms" value="Yes"></label>
  <label>No<input type="radio" name="sq_symptoms" value="No"></label>
</fieldset>
```

```php
// laravel validation
sq_symptoms: ['required', 'in:Yes,No']
```

```php
// using the Rule facade
sq_symptoms: ['required', Rule::in(['Yes', 'No'])]
```

---

There are no `for` or `id` attributes needed in this example. To explain why, here's an extract of [MDN's documentation on the `<label>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

> To associate the `<label>` with an `<input>` element, you need to give the
> `<input>` an `id` attribute. The `<label>` then needs a `for` attribute whose
> value is the same as the input's `id`.
>
> Alternatively, you can nest the `<input>` directly inside the `<label>`,
> in which case the `for` and `id` attributes are not needed because the
> association is **implicit**:

Comment: I currently has this as my `radio` insert

Comment: `       <br><br>
        <input type="radio" id="sqsymptoms" name="sqsymptoms" value="Yes"><label for="sqsymptoms">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" id="sqsymptoms" name="sqsymptoms" value="No"><label for="sqsymptoms">No</label><br>
        <br><br>`

Comment: That will not work. `<label for="sqsymptoms">` looks for the `<input id="sqsymptoms">`. Ids must be unique. That's why one of your radio buttons is not working. Try using `<label> <input> </label>`  syntax  instead (no `for` or `id` attributes needed!) for radio/checkboxes. Like in the example I posted. More information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: Alternatively, give your inputs unique ids. `<label for="sqlsymptoms-yes">Yes</label><input id="sqlsymptoms-yes" name="sqlsymptoms" value="Yes">` `<label for="sqlsymptoms-no">No</label><input id="sqlsymptoms-no" name="sqlsymptoms" value="No">`